# Rutas sin hashtag en Angularjs, problema al recargar la página ¿como se soluciona?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recientemente encontré la manera de quitar el hashtag de la url de las app en angularjs, ese # que se ve poco estético, edite mi app.js el archivo donde pongo los módulos y relaciono los paquetes de esta manera

```
]) .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

y en el index va esto

```
base href="/"
```

Y funciona perfecto me elimina el hashtag de la url, el problema es que al recargar la pagina, me dice que no encuentra la url error 404, ¿porque pasa esto?, ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que esto ya no depende de angular, sino del webserver que estés usando para ejecutar tu app. Si no estoy mal, se configuran de manera distinta en IIS, apache o lo que sea que uses. Si tuviera una respuesta exacta te la daría, pero solo puedo recomendarte que busques la solucion a traves de configuracion del server, y no de código en angular.

Comment: Si lo se pero no me funciona ninguno, lo estoy corriendo en un server local con un server de node que es "artesanal" donde subo el .dist, he encontrado soluciones para apache, ISS y otros pero no para mi caso en particular, pero por lo menos entendí que la configuración debe hacerse en el lado del servidor como dices.

Comment: Efectivamente, necesitas un enrutamiento para que los paths te envíen a tu página principal. En esta pregunta tratan ese mismo tema, seguramente te pueda ayudar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31547963/3382947

Comment: Por cierto, he lanzado una edición para añadir la etiqueta `nodejs` y que sea más fácil de identificar la respuesta que necesitas. No obstante, sería recomendable que lo comentaras en la propia pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Hola el servidor tiene que servir los estaticos en modo pushstate. 
Podes probar esto con un paquete de npm [BUDO](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) y correr el siguiente comando en la raiz de tu proyecto donde se encuentra tu index.html

`budo --pushstate`

Independientemente de la tecnología que implementes para que funcione el ruteo del modohtml5 es necesario este settings. [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)